# Map reduce's code python with an error 'string index out of range'

Tags: python, dictionary, reduce

My data looks like:

```
 1 1.45
 1 1.153
 2 2.179
 2 2.206
 2 2.59
 2 2.111
 3 3.201
 3 3.175
 4 4.228
 4 4.161
 4 4.213
```

The output I want is :

```
 1  2  (1 occurs 2 times)
 2  4
 3  2
 4  3
```

For this I run the following code:

```
SubPatent2count = {}
for line in data.split('\n'):
    for num in line.split('\t'):
        Mapper_data = ["%s\t%d" % (num[0], 1) ]
        for line in Mapper_data:
            Sub_Patent,count = line.strip().split('\t',1)
            try:
                count = int(count)
            except ValueError:
                continue

            try:
                SubPatent2count[Sub_Patent] = SubPatent2count[Sub_Patent]+count
            except:
                SubPatent2count[Sub_Patent] = count
for Sub_Patent in SubPatent2count.keys():
    print ('%s\t%s'% ( Sub_Patent,  SubPatent2count[Sub_Patent] ))
```

At the end I get this error :

```
     3    for num in line.split('\t'):
     4         #print(num[0])
----> 5         Mapper_data = ["%s\t%d" % (num[0], 1) ]
     6         #print(Mapper_data)
     7         for line in Mapper_data:

IndexError: string index out of range
```

If you have any Idea how I can deal with this error please Help. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just suggesting another approach: Have you tried with list comprehension + [groupy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from `itertools`?

```
from itertools import groupby

print([(key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby([x.split(' ')[0] for x in data.split('\n')])])
# where [x.split(' ')[0] for x in data.split('\n')] generates a list of all starting number
# and groupy counts them
```

Or if you want that exact output:

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [(key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby([x.split(' ')[0] for x in data.split('\n')])]


for key, repetition in mylist:
    print(key, repetition)
```

Comment: print [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby([x.split(' ')[0] for x in data.split('\n')])]
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I didn't see that yo were using python3: add parenthesis for the print statement: `print([len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby([x.split(' ')[0] for x in data.split('\n')])])`

Comment: Thank you for replying your code works but it gives an output that seems like []

Comment: [2,4,2,3] not as 1  2  (1 occurs 2 times)
 2  4
 3  2
 4  3

Comment: Edited the answer: now the list comprehension returns a list of tuple of 2 values, where the first value represent the number and the second value represent it's occurence. Note that `type(key)` is a `str` and `type(occurence)` is an `int`

Answer (score 0):

`num[0]` is probably an empty string, that's why you are getting an index out of range error. Another possibility is that you are in fact separating the number in each line with empty strings, not with tabs.

Anyway, your code seems a little strange. For example, you encode the data in a string in a list of one element (`Mapped_data`) and then decode it to process it. That is really not necessary and you should avoid it.

Try this code:

```
from collections import Counter

decoded_data = [ int(l.split(' ', 1)[0]) for l in data.split('\n') if len(l)>0]
SubPatent2count = Counter(decoded_data)

for k in SubPatent2count:
    print k, SubPatent2count[k]
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. In fact **num[0]** is not empty, if you print it it gives: ( 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 )

Comment: I tried the code it gives the following error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 1.232'

Comment: it is probably the last line, that is an empty string, because the las line ends with `\n`.

Comment: The error it is probably because the numbers are not separated by a tab, but with an empty space. Try replacing  the `'\t'` with `' '`.

Comment: I tried to change the '\t' with '  ' but t gives the following error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Comment: try the code with the last edition, that added the condition: `if len(l) >0`. The problem is that the last line has a `\n`, and hence, the split is returning an empty string as the last line.

Comment: I'm sorry but even though it still gives the error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 1.232'. I think we should first get the beginning number of each line

Comment: I told you to replace the tab literal: `'\t'` by the space literal `' '`, but you replace it with the empty literal `''`.

Comment: I did replace it with '   ' here is the error:   ----> 3 decoded_data = [ int(l.split('  ', 1)[0]) for l in data.split('\n')]
      4 SubPatent2count = Counter(decoded_data)
      5 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 1.232'

Comment: @JijiAR what I read in your comment is `''` where it should be `' '`. I changed the code in the answer, try with that please.

Comment: thank you for replying, I tried you code but it gives me this error:      'Counter' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: You must be using a different version of python. Try iterating as with dictionaries. See update of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody, your suggestions really helped me, I changed my code as follow:

```
SubPatent2count = {}
for line in data.split('\n'):
Mapper_data = ["%s\o%d" % (line.split(' ')[0], 1) ]
    for line in Mapper_data:
            Sub_Patent,count = line.strip().split('\o',1)
            try:
                count = int(count)
            except ValueError:
                continue

            try:
                SubPatent2count[Sub_Patent] = SubPatent2count[Sub_Patent]+count
           except:
                SubPatent2count[Sub_Patent] = count
for Sub_Patent in SubPatent2count.keys():
    print ('%s\t%s'% ( Sub_Patent,  SubPatent2count[Sub_Patent] ))
```

And it gives the following result:

```
1  2  (1 occurs 2 times)
2  4
3  2
4  3
```

Comment: You kept this pattern where you encode the data to decode it later to process it. This code also has a `for` loop that is really unnecessary, because you are iterating a list of just one element, a list you have just created. I insist you should not do that. All the solutions offered in the answers are way better than this.